# accessing a variable in a different function

Tags: javascript, function

I have this function that determines the id of the clicked element. I need to store it as a variable that I can use in another function.

```
$(".loadlist").click(function() {

     var folderid;
     folderid =jQuery(this).attr('id') || ''
      $("#adults").swap({
      target: "table1_wrapper",
      opacity: "0.5",
      speed: 1000,   
});
});
```

The second function is

```
 jQuery(document).on("click", "#trigger_adults", function (event) {
 folderName = "/sites/bi/adultslibrary/";
fullpath = folderName + folderid;


  $().SPServices({
      webUrl: "http://onespace.nottscc.gov.uk/sites/bihub",
      operation: "GetListItems",
      async: false,
      listName: "adultslibrary",
      CAMLRowLimit: 100,
      CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>
     <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' /> 
     <FieldRef Name='EncodedAbsUrl'/>  
     <FieldRef Name='Year'/> 
     <FieldRef Name='Snapshot'/></ViewFields> " ,
     CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><Folder>"+fullpath+ "</Folder></QueryOptions>",
 // everything else
```

I need to be able to access the folder id variable in the second function so I can use it to concatenate the url path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to defining your variables **gloabally**, as mentioned in other answers, I believe the issue is that you aren't wrapping your Javascript in a document.onready function.

Anyways, the following worked for me:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="loadlist" id="1">
  LoadList
</div>

<br><br>

<div id="trigger_adults">
  #trigger_adults
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {

    var folderid;
    var folderName;
    var fullpath;

    $(".loadlist").click(function() {

      folderid = jQuery(this).attr('id') || '';

    });

    jQuery(document).on("click", "#trigger_adults", function(event) {

      folderName = "/sites/bi/adultslibrary/";
      fullpath = folderName + folderid;

      alert(fullpath);

    });

  });
</script>
```

If all else fails, make sure that your version of jQuery is v1.7 or newer.

Comment: That cracked it! Thank you very much for your help. If I could buy you a pint I would :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable outside of both functions like this:

```
var mySpecialId;
$(".loadlist").click(function() {
    mySpecialId = xxx;
    ...
});
$().SPServices({
    do something with mySpecialId
    ... 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the variable outside the scope of the function invoked when `.loadlist` is clicked.

```
var folderid;
$(".loadlist").click(function() {


   folderid =jQuery(this).attr('id') || ''
   $("#adults").swap({
     target: "table1_wrapper",
     opacity: "0.5",
     speed: 1000,   
   });
});
```

And then your second function:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#trigger_adults", function (event) {
  folderName = "/sites/bi/adultslibrary/";
  fullpath = folderName + folderid;
  //...
```

You can also see this in action here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhuq9brb/)

Comment: Hi thanks for responding

I've tried this but the folderid seems to hold a value of undefined. I've  made an alert for the variable fullpath and it ends up "/sites/bi/adultslibrary/undefined"

Comment: Then folderid is not set correctly in the scope outside your two functions, I think